# Obtain number of token in a string with java Scanner

Tags: java

Is there a way to obtain the number of token in a string obtained by Method Scanner in Java?

I mean, i can use `s = sc.nextLine()` to obtain an input line as a string. But on this string I cannot use `lenght()` method cause it gives me the total number of characters (I think).

Are existing any standard methods to obtain the number of token?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is no such way. Scanner gives you next token when you have entered it. It means, it doesn't _know_ how many tokens it has.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
int frequency = new StringTokenizer(myString, " ").countTokens();
```

For more details see [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#countTokens%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `Scanner` cannot do token counting without consuming these tokens from the input. So in order to access those tokens, you have to save them in a list:

```
List<String> tokens = new LinkedList<String>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = 0;
while(sc.hasNext()) {
  tokens.add(sc.next());
  count++;
}
System.out.println("Number of tokens: "+count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(token);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
int count = 0;
// Check all occurrences
while (matcher.find()) {
    ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could manage it using the `split` method:

```java
public static int getTokenCount(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    input = input.trim();
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return input.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()`, it supports regex, unlike `StringTokenizer`.

```
int nbOfTokens = sc.nextLine().split(sc.delimiter().pattern()).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        String delims= "[ .,'!?_@]+";
        int length1=s.split(delims).length;

        System.out.println(length1);
        String[] tokens=s.split(delims);
        for(String token : tokens){
            System.out.println(token);

        }


        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please also explain the Code? As Code only answers, may solve the Problem, but do not help others to understand.